# Searching a list across a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Currently, I have a database built in R that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(c('ABC','DEF','HIJ'),
                 c(1,2,5),
                 c(2,5,9),
                 c(14,19,12))
```

And I have a function which searches for one value across the entire data frame and returns the entire row, the function for this is below:

```
df[which(df == 5,
            arr.ind = TRUE)[,"row"],]
```

This function returns the following when executed:

```
 HIJ 5 9 12
 DEF 2 5 19
```

I would like to be able to enter a list of values as a vector and then filter through all the values in one shot using a loop to return values that have a match, however, I have been totally lost in creating a loop function with my search function above to find values from a vector in my dataset. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve, by searching for values from vector **v** across data frame **df** to return all rows of **df** which have values in any column or row that are the same as values in **v**:

```
v <- c(1,2,13,19,16,120,2934,1087)
```

Searching this across the data frame I would like to return:

```
 HIJ 5 9 12
 DEF 2 5 19
```

I am wondering what would be the best way to perform a loop to do this search?

Comment: Why isn't `ABC` returned? 1 & 2 are both in `v`

Answer (score 1):

We can use :

```
df[rowSums(sapply(df, `%in%`, v)) > 0, ]
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. %in% v))
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to reshape your data first. I'll use `data.table::melt`:

```
library(data.table)
df = data.frame(
  V1 = c("ABC", "DEF", "HIJ"), 
  V2 = c(1, 2, 5), 
  V3 = c(2, 5, 9), 
  V4 = c(14, 19, 12)
)
setDT(df)

# reshape long
melt_df = melt(df, id.vars = 'V1')
melt_df
#        V1 variable value
# 1:    ABC       V2     1
# 2:    DEF       V2     2
# 3:    HIJ       V2     5
# 4:    ABC       V3     2
# 5:    DEF       V3     5
# 6:    HIJ       V3     9
# 7:    ABC       V4    14
# 8:    DEF       V4    19
# 9:    HIJ       V4    12
```

Now we can look it all up at once:

```
melt_df[value %in% v]
#        V1 variable value
# 1:    ABC       V2     1
# 2:    DEF       V2     2
# 3:    ABC       V3     2
# 4:    DEF       V4    19
```

That's the gist of it. To get back your original desired output, we need to do some other steps:

```
df[.(V1 = melt_df[value %in% v, unique(V1)]), on = 'V1']
#        V1    V2    V3    V4
# 1:    ABC     1     2    14
# 2:    DEF     2     5    19
```

this pulls the associated values of `V1` from `melt_df` (`unique` removes duplicates) and *joins them back to `df`* (hence `on='V1'`) to get the associated rows from `df`